# Excel Macro Warning if Cell exceeds Value

Tags: excel, vba

im really new to VBA and Excel Macros in general, so im seeking for help.

I have a cell that displays the amount of rows my query will load into another worksheet.
Since excel only allows 1048576 rows, I want a macro in the background that displays a warning (msgbox) if the cell displays a higher value than the limit.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use Conditional Formating rule to highlight the cell

Comment: For cases like this, I usually just display a warning in an adjacent cell. Could this be sufficient in your case? Something like ```=IF(C1>1048576,"WARNING: Max value exceeded","")```

Comment: I agree with and add to @FranzReischl 's comment:  Format that adjacent cell with a bold/red font.  You won't miss it !  You can create other checks, on the same (or other) entry cells,  using the same method -- each test in its own cell.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done indeed, using the built-in `Worksheet_Change` event, as in the following example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const WatchAddress = "C10"    ' modify to your needs
    Dim Sentinel As Range
    Dim MaxRowCount as Long
    Set Sentinel = Me.Range(WatchAddress)
    MaxRowCount = Me.Rows.Count   ' modify to your needs
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sentinel) is Nothing Then
        If Sentinel.Value > MaxRowCount Then
           MsgBox "Query is too big: " & Sentinel.Value, vbCritical, Me.Name
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

For your information:

- `C10` is an address where you keep  the amount of rows of your query to load
- You may need to set `MaxRowCount = Me.Rows.Count - 1` because of a header row, which is usual in this case
- This only happens if `C10` is changed, whether alone or with some other cells simultaneously.

Comment: This code fails if the target contains more than just the cell of interest. Better use `Intersect` in this case.

Comment: @Vitalizzare: can you modify my answer accordingly?

Comment: At the moment "Suggested edit queue is full". I don't know what that means, but I can't edit your answer right now. I did prepare an answer though, so maybe later.

Comment: @Vitalizzare: I just tried editing my answer and there is no problem. If you keep having issues, you might copy your answer in a comment and I'll edit my answer.